# Greater number of activity classes increase the app size ?? Help needed

Tags: android

I am creating a basic app with health tips. I need screens to get loaded one after another in a sequential manner. Should I create as many activities as the number of tips [1 activity for 1 tip] ?? I guess this wont be economical. Any alternate ways ??

Thanks !!

Comment: You should not have one activity per tip, you should have one activity per "function", so to speak. What you do is that you update the current activity programmatically (in java code)

Comment: I believe for your case best will be to have one tip per swipe.

Comment: what is tip? Is it image or textual information only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I create as many activities as the number of tips?

No,`its effect the performance of  your app`.You have to change content of view programmatically.

I think you have option [Fragment.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) .To show many views in one Activity.